# Search Map Coordinates in Multiple Boundaries

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have some code that asks the user for an address and using GoogleMaps API, returns the geocode Lat/Long of that address.  I already have it set up to query if these coordinates fall within a pre-determined boundary.  What I would like to do is have a multiple boundaries and be able to search through them and return a result.  For example, I would have some JSON data or some other type of array that contained the SW_LatLng, NE_LatLng and  an Answer.  So my query would use the following function and if true return the answer.  My question is how do I loop through multiple boundaries and return the result.

```
bounds.contains(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude));
```

Here is the code I already have:

```
function codeAddress() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(37,-109),
        new google.maps.LatLng(41, -102)
    );
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

      }
      var center = bounds.getCenter();
      var x = bounds.contains(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude));

      if (x) { alert('In Colorado')} else { alert('Outside Colorado')};

    });
  }

<h3>Is your Address in Colorado?</h3>
<input id="address" type="textbox" style="width:60%">
<input type="button" value="Find" onclick="codeAddress()">
```

I have this set up in a CodePen (like JSFiddle) for you to play with.

[CodePen Link](http://cdpn.io/ocgvh)

Any help is appreciated.  Also, what is the best way to keep the data hidden?

Here is the JSFiddle Link [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/guhru/hQ8QU/7/)

Comment: Your code in fiddle and codepen is broken: `Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined `

Comment: I fixed the JSFiddle so it works now.  The CodePen works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using polygons to define your boundaries? Then using the google maps api containsLocation method (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation) in the Geometry library to determine if the point lies within the boundaries?

You seem to be limited to just rectangular regions (this may be good enough for your purpose, I don't know I'm just making a suggestion).

Either way, as you said you need to loop through your array of latitude/longitude boundary pairs (call this `latLngArray`).

```
function codeAddress() {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        }

        var latLngArrayLength = latLngArray.getLength();

        for (i=0; i<latLngArrayLength; i++) {
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                new google.maps.LatLng(latLngArray[i].latSW, latLngArray[i].lngSW)
                new google.maps.LatLng(latLngArray[i].latNE, latLngArray[i].lngNE)
            );

            var center = bounds.getCenter(); //what is this for??
            var x = bounds.contains(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude));

            if (x) { 
                alert('In ' + latLngArray[i].boundaryName); //not sure what you want to return exactly
                return latLngArray[i].boundaryName;
            }
        }  
    });
}
```